# How to click on child element from parent

Tags: reactjs

I have two components:
`Parent.js`

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  handleTagHierClick(e) {
    var excel = this.refs.workbook;
    excel.click();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleTagHierClick(e)} className="btn btn-default btn-block">Download Tag Hier</button>
      <Child/>
    )
  }
}
```

And `Child.js`

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref='workbook'></div>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I trigger a click on the `div` element from the `Child` component when I click on the `button` element from the `Parent` component? I tried with `ref` but that won't work since the elements are on different components...

Comment: if that is parent and child why aren't you rendering child in parent's render function?

Comment: I will have more than one components that will call that `Child` component and I don't want to duplicate the code..

Comment: check answer is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37950970/5293976

Comment: first of all this is not a Parent / Child relationship according to your code. and second, what exactly are you trying to do? triggering clicks often lead to a "hacky" pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you do it like

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

 handleTagHierClick(e) {
     this.child.someMethod();
 }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <Child ref={(obj) => { this.child = obj; }}/>
      <button
         onClick={(e) => this.handleTagHierClick(e)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside child

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  someMethod(){
      // Here you can trigger click on the div
      this.div.click();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div  ref={(obj) => { this.div = obj; }}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a ref to the button?

```
<button ref='myButton'...
```

Then replace the variable excel by:

```
var excel = this.refs.myButton.refs.workbook;
```

Comment: That returns `Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined` on `this.refs.myButton.refs.workbook;`

Comment: this is the old API for refs which is not supported anymore.